# Append Copied Cell at specific index into table - Apps script | Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have two tables with same no of columns and rows.

I want to copy 1st cell (in first row)  from second table and paste it into the first cell (in first row) in 1st table. I tried appending the cell but it appends to the end of row 1 in table 1 and don't at start. I want to copy other cells too from 2nd table and replace them with the ones in 1st table but appending cell method don't allow me to insert cells in first table at specific index in a row.

I can try copying text from cell of 2nd table to cell of table 1 because i have specific formatting that losts when i tried copying. I want to copy all content along with formatting from a cell. I need help to do this.

My script:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(my_doc_id);//copy.getId()); 
var body = doc.getBody(); 
var tables = body.getTables()


var c1 = tables[1].getRow(0).getCell(0).copy();
tables[0].getRow(0).appendTableCell(c1);



}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Khp.png)

I tried copying text from cell of 2nd table to cell of table 1 because i have specific formatting that losts when i tried copying. I want to copy all content along with formatting from a cell. I need help to do this.

Please see the screenshot attached. I have two tables: (1) 1st table with checklist items (unchecked boxes). (2) 2nd table with checklist items (checked boxes). 2nd table is exact copy of 1st but just the boxes are checked. Now, if i want to tick a any checkbox in table 1, then i want to simply copy that cell from table 2 and paste it into table 1.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I want to copy other cells to from 2nd table and replace them with the ones in 1st table but appending cell method don't allow me to insert cells in first table at specific index in a row.`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue and your goal?

Comment: Please see the screenshot attached. I have two tables: 

(1) 1st table with checklist items (unchecked boxes).
(2) 2nd table with checklist items (checked boxes).

2nd table is exact copy of 1st but just the boxes are checked.

Now, if i want to tick a any checkbox in table 1, then i want to simply copy that cell from table 2 and paste it into table 1. 

Hope, that makes sense?